# vscode dev containers custom templates

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I've got a company internal devcontainer template and feature repository. I can apply templates with the devcontainer CLI but I can't figure out how to use them with the VSCode extension.
When using the vscode dev container wizard (via Add Dev Container Configuration...) how can I specify a full OCI image path? Can I point to a different image collection (via OCI path) to populate the available options?